# determine if the following converges or diverges using limit comparison Test [solved]

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

how would you show if this converges or diverges using limit comparison test

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{(3n+2)}{(4n^7-3)^\frac{1}{3}}$$

I know I must compare it to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{n^\frac{4}{3}}$$

however, I am still unable to determine how to show convergence or divergence. Please help

Comment: Are you familiar with the p-test?  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^p}$$ converges for p>1.

Comment: yes, I am and because p is more than 1 it should converge but I would like to know how I would show it using the limit as n tends to infinite of the quotient of the two series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the order of growth of the summands as a function of $n$: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{3n+2}{(4n^7 -3)^{1/3}} &= \frac{(3+2n^{-1})n}{((4 -3n^{-7})n^7)^{1/3}}  \\
    &= \frac{(3+2n^{-1})n}{(4 -3n^{-7})^{1/3}n^{7/3}}  \\
    &= \frac{(3+2n^{-1})}{(4 -3n^{-7})^{1/3}} \cdot \frac{n}{n^{7/3}}  \\
    &= \frac{(3+2n^{-1})}{(4 -3n^{-7})^{1/3}} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}
\end{align*}
For the limit comparison test, we verify
\begin{align*}
3n+2 \geq 2 &> 0, \text{ if } n \geq 1,  \text{ and }  \\
(4n^7 -3)^{1/3} \geq (4-3)^{1/3} = 1 &> 0, \text{ if } n \geq 1,  \text{ so }  \\
\frac{3n+2}{(4n^7 -3)^{1/3}} &> 0, \text{ if } n \geq 1
\end{align*}
and also $1/n^{4/3} > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$.  Then we study
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{3n+2}{(4n^7 -3)^{1/3}}}{\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}}
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{(3+2n^{-1})}{(4 -3n^{-7})^{1/3}} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}}{\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}}  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(3+2n^{-1})}{(4 -3n^{-7})^{1/3}}  \\
    &= \frac{3+0}{(4-0)^{1/3}}  \\
    &= \frac{3}{4^{1/3}}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since this is a positive, finite limit, either both series converge or both series diverge.

So, does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$ converge or diverge?

Comment: thank you very much. It makes sense now and I know it would converge as we are comparing with a p-series p > 1.